# How Do I Center "Quick Links" Section On Footer Of My Shopify Website

Tags: css, shopify, center, footer

I'm trying to center the "Quick Links" section on the footer of my Shopify website so both the word "Quick Links" and all the page links under it are centered on both desktop and mobile but I can't seem to find the solution, can somebody help me out?

The website is safeguardlenz.com and the password is: Bebe

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/OpL4nC

Comment: Then you can try it like this: `.site-footer__item:last-of-type { display: grid; place-items: center }`